# Three Derived Tables in one Query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, union, derived-table

I'm stuck again. I would like to combine some Tables, which have the exact same column names.

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Games) FROM
(SELECT ID, Games FROM Table1
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT ID, Games FROM Table2
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT ID, Games FROM Table3
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT ID, Games FROM Table4) AS derivedTable
GROUP BY ID ORDER BY Games
```

It works fine. However, Table1 and Table2 belong to one League, while Table3 and 4 belong to another.

Thats why I would like to call the values of Table1 + 2 and also Table 2 + 3 AND the Total amount, for ordering them by the total amount.

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Games) FROM
(
 (SELECT ID, Games FROM Table1
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT ID, Games FROM Table2) AS A

 (SELECT ID, Games FROM Table3
 UNION ALL 
 SELECT ID, Games FROM Table4) AS B
) AS derivedTable
GROUP BY ID ORDER BY Games
```

And on my website, i would like to echo Sum(A.Games), Sum(B.Games) and Sum(Total.Games) to show the games played in the different leagues and most important the total amount.

Or is it possible to link the order gathered by the first query and start a second query (for table1 + table2 only) where the order should be used from the first query?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: what stands the ID for?

Comment: What's wrong with the second query?

Comment: why have you got separate tables in the first place, if they all contain the same kind of data? If the tables simply represent different leagues, then your data is de-normalised. Instead you'd have just one table for all this data, and an extra column "League ID" to tell you which league each row of data belongs to. Then this kind of query would be much simpler to write. As a general rule if you find yourself having to write this kind of convoluted SQL to get something simple like a SUM, then it's probably a symptom of a bad design.

Comment: I think relation is missing between table A and table B

Comment: mech: 
Inside the Tables are players who participated in these leagues. Each ID is connected with one player, so it is easy to get the total amount of games played by the Player with ID 1.

MeesKluivers 
If I test this code in my sql server, it just says "error in SQL-syntax" 

ADyson
 I know that, but for my purpose and usage it is most easy to handle the data (and update it weekly) to seperate the tables like that, and for most parts of my website it is still easy to combine the tables the way I want - except for this specific case...

Comment: " for my purpose and usage it is most easy to handle the data (and update it weekly) to seperate the tables like that"...sorry but I disagree. How can it be easier to have separate tables than just a value in a column? You are violating the principles of relational database design and that is the root cause of the problem you're currently having. The correct solution is to re-design the schema.